# GitHub Workflow Actions Doxygen "no files to be processed"

Tags: github, github-actions, github-pages, doxygen

I am trying to set up GitHub workflow action for automatically generating and publishing a documentation for some C++ project on GitHub. I have created a directory called .github/workflows in the git repository of the project, and in this directory I have added a ".yml" file taken from the following link,

https://github.com/satu0king/Github-Documentation-With-Doxygen/blob/master/main.yml

This ".yml" is supposed to set up the doxygen action if the path for the doxyfile is provided in the ".yml" file, which I also did. Now when I lunch the runner for this action Doxyggen seems to work fine and the doxyfile is recognized, but in the output I read "no files to be processed".

So Doxygen is not seeing the source code, although "Recursive" is set to "Yes" in my doxyfile. Due to my lack of experience with GitHub actions I ask for help. Thank you.

Comment: Most likely  your `INPUT` directory is not the directory you / doxygen expects it to be, I don't think this workflow ever worked did it?